# Map array, iterate nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, nested

Please refer to the following code:

```
x = 3
arr = ("a".."z").to_a
arr2 = [1, 2, arr[ i ], 4]
arr3 = arr2.map * x
```

Desired output:

```
arr3 # => 12a412b412c4
```

What is the best practice to achieve this output?

Comment: What is `i`? ...............

Comment: @sawa: I believe it is supposed to be the index of the `map` in the following line... a bit of time travel...

Comment: Have seen i used as a counter variable in other examples.  In this case would like arr's index to count up along with the number of times arr2 is mapped to arr3.

Comment: Brendan, I see you've received 4 votes to close. That's too bad, as there are some interesting answers. I hope you will edit to clarify the question. Those who have answered have all made the same assumption about what you want. If they are correct, I suggest you just show your given inputs and desired output. `arr2` is expecially a problem, since `i` is not defined. This often happens, incidentally, when someone posts a question and then walks away.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't walked away.  This is the second time to post a question here on stack overflow.  So I apologize for not knowing the rules of conduct.  Haven't meant to offend.  And greatly appreciate everyone's answers.

Comment: I'm perplexed why you won't clarify your question with an edit. For information on how SO works, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

```
("a"..."z").first(3).map{|chr| [1, 2, chr, 4]}.join
# => "12a412b412c4"
```

Comment: cool solution. I suggest if you replace `3` with `x` it looks more similar to OP's requirement

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you are doing, so sticking as close to to your original code:

```
x = 3
arr = ("a".."z").to_a
arr2_generator = lambda { |i| [1, 2, arr[i], 4] }
arr3 = x.times.map(&arr2_generator)
puts arr3.join
```

There is no way to use `i` before you actually define it, and no way to define it statically because it changes from one instance to another - i.e. there is no way to write `arr2` such that it would change later. Instead, we use a lambda expression, that will accept an `i` and give `[1, 2, arr[i], 4]`.

Finally, if you just print the array, you will get one element per row; so I use `join` to smush everything into one string.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Good point; I ignored that `join` flattens the list.

Comment: What does the & do in line 4?

Comment: Promotes the `Proc` created by `lambda` into a block.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum = ('a'..'z').to_enum
3.times.map { [1,2,enum.next,4] }.join
  #=> "12a412b412c4"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-c-new) with a block:

```
x = 3
arr = ("a".."z").to_a
Array.new(x) { |i| [1, 2, arr[i], 4] }.join
#=> "12a412b412c4"
```